# Import multiple watch-only addresses using importaddress?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, address, json-rpc, import

With the [importaddress](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#importaddress) RPC command it is possible to import one watch-only address.
But how can I do that with, let's say, 100?

Answer (score 7):

There is an alternate command `importmulti` to be used as follows:

```
bitcoin-cli importmulti '[
{
  "scriptPubKey" : { "address": "mxbvcPj7cnbxPP6oqpHJxxNb4xC8QoLquG" },
  "timestamp" : 0,
  "label" : "mxbvcPj7cnbxPP6oqpHJxxNb4xC8QoLquG"
},
{
  "scriptPubKey" : { "address": "n1iNb8XafoJTrCBBcGSSEZ6YNd6EWYo8PU" },
  "timestamp" : 0,
  "label" : "n1iNb8XafoJTrCBBcGSSEZ6YNd6EWYo8PU"
},
{
  "scriptPubKey" : { "address": "mgLs7quWwYBJa7jkZyebAec7RNXQtwaerK" },
  "timestamp" : 0,
  "label" : "mgLs7quWwYBJa7jkZyebAec7RNXQtwaerK"
}]' '{"rescan":false}'
```

Response is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "success": true
  }, 
  {
    "success": true
  }, 
  {
    "success": true
  }
]
```

Comment: No need for the labels.

Answer (score 4):

The RPC interface doesn't generally provide any "batch mode" functionality.  If you want to import 100 addresses, call `importaddress` 100 times.  You might like to write a short script with a loop in some other language.

You should set the rescan parameter to `false` for all but the last address, so that you don't trigger rescanning 100 times.