# Can I generate an address without using bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, address, address-generation, listunspent

I am running bitcoin core in my mode. I am using **getnewaddress** to generate an address and then I am using **unspent** to get the **unspent** of an address which returns the unspent successfully. If I created an address without using **getnewaddress** (using some 3rd party or offline) and when I am using **unspent** on that address it is not giving the **unspent** instead it is returning an empty list. Could anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: I think you are maybe looking for watch only addresses, e.g.: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#importaddress or also here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48829/import-multiple-watch-only-addresses-using-importaddress

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin Core does not store the information for all addresses as that would be computationally expensive and not very useful. For you to get this data, the address needs to be part of your wallet. So you must add the address to the wallet using `importaddress` and allow Bitcoin Core to rescan the blockchain. It will then find all of the transactions related to that address and look for new transactions related to that address. Note that rescanning can take a long time so if you want to import multiple addresses, use `importmulti`.